# Getting time delta with two different timestamps, one has UTC Stamp, the other does not

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

I have a date/time stamp that I store in MongoDB. I am trying to do a delta_t calculation from the current time vs whatever the timestamp is in the database.

MongoDB shows the database format as `2020-12-17T19:43:56.000+00:00`. Here is my code so far:

```
curr_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
last_time = old_stats['last_update'] #retrieving the timestamp from the database
dt = int((last_time - curr_time).total_seconds())
```

**The issue:**

But basically my time calculation ends up being ~7 hours off.

**My idea:**

I have a feeling it has to do with my current time format, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can parse the input format to aware datetime (UTC) with `datetime.fromisoformat`. How does `last_time` look like (dtype/format)?

Comment: I am not familiar with python but it looks like you have a `datetime`, convert it to a string and then convert it back again to a `datetime`, this seems to be pointless. Work only with `datetime` values, use strings only for the final display at the client application.